# get MongoBinData value from mongo shell

Tags: php, mongodb

I save IP in mongo

```
$db = new MongoClient();

$db->selectCollection('test', 'test')->insert([
    'ip'=> new MongoBinData(inet_pton('127.0.0.1'), MongoBinData::BYTE_ARRAY),
]);
```

mongo shell

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54e1aeeb84663f3407000030"), "ip" : BinData(2,"BAAAAH8AAAE=") }
```

how to get initial data in mongo shell?

Comment: Have you tried to do this: `foreach ($collection->find() as $el) {
    echo $doc['ip']->bin;
}`. I think it should help, but I do not have php to verify this now, so please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Also, unless I misunderstand the question, I think you should change the title since you are trying to retrieve the BinData value using PHP, not using the mongo shell.

Comment: @wdberkeley hi, i have only string "BAAAAH8AAAE=", how to i get initial value without insert/fetch data in mongodb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the hexdump of what ends up in mongod, versus what you insert should clarify a lot:

```
$ php -r 'echo inet_pton("127.0.0.1");'|hexdump 
0000000 007f 0100                              
0000004

$ php -r 'echo base64_decode("BAAAAH8AAAE=");'|hexdump 
0000000 0004 0000 007f 0100                    
0000008
```

This shows that the original 4 bytes end up prefixed by another 4 bytes in mongodb. The reason for this can be found in [the BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), when storing a Binary, the first 4 bytes will store the length of the value it contains.

This also hints as to what the solution is; after a little fiddling (I've never used mongodb), I ended up with:

```
> db.test.find().forEach(function(d){
    var h = d.ip.hex();
    print(
            parseInt(h.substr(8,2), 16)+'.'
            +parseInt(h.substr(10,2), 16)+'.'
            +parseInt(h.substr(12,2), 16)+'.'
            +parseInt(h.substr(14,2), 16));
    });
```

This will result in your desired output: `127.0.0.1`